# Can the same linear operation be applied to both the input and output of a linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, proof-writing, operator-theory, linear-transformations

"The scientist and engineers guide to digital signal processing", Steven W. Smith, p. 134, 135
states:

'...imagine a linear system receiving an input signal, x[n]. and generating an output signal, y[n].  Now suppose the input signal is changed in some linear way, resulting in a new input signal, which we will call x'[n].  This results in a new output signal, y'[n].  The question is, how does the change in the input signal relate to the change in the output signal?  The answer is: *the output signal is changed in exactly the same linear way that the input signal was changed*....A linear change made to the input signal results in the same linear change to the output signal.'

see p. 134,135 [www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch7.pdf](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch7.pdf)

I assume this statement can be written for the continuous case as:

if y = L(x) then M(y) = L(M(x)), where L, M are linear operators, and x, y are functions.

**For the continuous case my question is:** *Is this true?*

Also is there a theorem on this?  Is there a proof?  Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327258/2451

Comment: @user45664: If you edit your question to change it, can you please notify the author of the previous answer? Or at least comment on why the answer is not sufficient? What do you mean by "the continuous case": which variable is continuous?

Comment: By continuous I mean, say, x(t) and y(t) vs x[n] and y[n] as in the quoted text.  I should have used f and g instead of x and y -- sorry.  I would like the answer for continuous linear operators vs sampled data (or discrete) operators.  When Smith states x[n] he is talking about x[1], x[2] .. x[n], not a continuous function like x(t), where t is a continuous variable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your original linear system is $y = Lx$, where $L$ is a linear transformation. The input $x$ is changed via the linear operator $M$ to produce $x' = Mx$, and in turn $y' = LMx$.

The difference in the input signals is a vector $d_x$ such that $x + d_x = x'$. We have that $$d_x = x' - x = Mx - x = (M - I)x$$
where $I$ is the identity operator.

The difference in the output signals is a vector $d_y$ such that $y + d_y = y'$. We have that $$d_y = y' - y = LMx - Lx = L(M - I)x = Ld_x$$

So we conclude that $d_y = Ld_x$, so the difference vectors transform linearly under the operator $L$, regardless of whatever the transformation $M$ was.