# Need verification of proof that a linear operation can be applied to the input and output of a linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, reference-request, operator-theory, linear-transformations

The statement "Can you apply a linear operation to the input and output of a linear operator?", can be written:

if $g = L(f)$ then does $M(g) = L(M(f))$,
where $L, M$ are linear (LTI) operators, and $f, g$ are functions?

Here is an attempt at a proof that this statement is true:

Since all linear LTI operators on functions can be represented as a convolution, *, of the input function with the operator's impulse response, 
let $Li$ and $Mi$ be the impulse responses of the LTI operators $L$ and $M$.

So $g = Li * f$

and since convolution is associative and commutative

$M(g) = Mi * [Li * f] = Mi * Li * f = Li * f * Mi = Li * [Mi * f] = L(M(f))$

which proves a linear operation can be applied to both the input and output of a LTI linear operator!

**My question is: Is this proof good? A book (with page numbers) or a published paper will be appreciated.**

Notes:

This attempts to provide a proof for
[Can the same linear operation be applied to both the input and output of a linear operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2235915/147776)

It builds on the answer to [Can all linear operators on functions be represented as a convolution of the input function with the operator's impulse response?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246853/147776)  ,

specifically the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2246879/147776  .

Comment: related question by OP https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/40499/28133

Comment: answer here needed for above related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246853/147776